# Python faker - Syntax error - CSV file

Tags: python, masking, faker

Python Syntax Error - CSV file input:
I'm trying to use CSV masking test for an implementation and picked up use case from [masking using faker](https://districtdatalabs.silvrback.com/a-practical-guide-to-anonymizing-datasets-with-python-faker). Picked up the sample code from the link and trying to execute the program. But I'm getting syntax error when accessing the csv file.

```
import unicodecsv as csv
from faker import Factory
from collections import defaultdict



def anonymize_rows(rows):
"""
Rows is an iterable of dictionaries that contain name and
email fields that need to be anonymized.
"""
# Load the faker and its providers
faker  = Factory.create()

# Create mappings of names & emails to faked names & emails.
names  = defaultdict(faker.name)
emails = defaultdict(faker.email)

# Iterate over the rows and yield anonymized rows.
for row in rows:
    # Replace the name and email fields with faked fields.
    row['name']  = names[row['name']]
    row['email'] = emails[row['email']]

    # Yield the row back to the caller
    yield row


   def anonymize('masktest.csv', 'masktest_tgt.csv'):
"""
The source argument is a path to a CSV file containing data to anonymize,
while target is a path to write the anonymized CSV data to.
"""
with open('masktest.csv', 'rU') as f:
     with open('masktest_tgt.csv', 'w') as o:
        # Use the DictReader to easily extract fields
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(o, reader.fieldnames)

        # Read and anonymize data, writing to target file.
        for row in anonymize_rows(reader):
            print (row['name'])
            writer.writerow(row)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 34
    def anonymize('masktest.csv', 'masktest_tgt.csv'):
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Yes, that line is not Python syntax. What would you expect it to do?

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont understand, can you please explain. How can I pass the input csv file into the function anonymize.I would like to pass the input and out CSV files to mask the data.  I was able to read from a file using - " with open('masktest.csv', 'rU') as f:
        reader=csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
         print(row['name']) " but the function doesnt work.

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect, please, fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the original definition, you'll see the correct syntax.

```
def anonymize(source, target):
    """
    The source argument is a path to a CSV file containing data to anonymize,
    while target is a path to write the anonymized CSV data to.
    """
    # more code...
```

What's different here, is that when you define a function, you must provide valid identifiers in parentheses. An identifier is essentially a name for the variable, what you'll use to refer to the argument inside your function.

Possibly, you meant to do one of the following things:

- *Call* a function, not *define* it. In that case, you shouldn't use the `def` keyword. A call looks like this: `func(arg1, arg2)`. The amount of values in parentheses should generally match up with the amount of identifiers in the function definition. And here, in place of `arg1` and `arg2`, you can use strings or any other literal values or variables that you've defined.
- Make function arguments optional. In this case, the string literals in parentheses should be preceded with an identifier and a `=` sign, like so: `def anonymize(arg1 = 'one', arg2 = 'two')`. This will allow you to call a function without a neccesity to provide all arguments. If an argument is not given a value, it will be assigned with a default one that you wrote in the definition. Valid calls will be: `anonymize('me')`, `anonymize()`, `anonymize(arg2 = 'you')`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help Leva. That cleared up my program and I have passed the literal values and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Word `def` is used only for defining function.

To call a function use its name and parameters without "def":

```
faked_values = anonimize('file.csv', 'file2.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you Eugene. I have just passed the variables with the values in the definition itself. ex:  def anonymize(source='masktest.csv', target='masktest_tgt.csv'):

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks. I have removed the function and just passed the input csv file name as a input and it worked like a charm. Here is the code.

```
import csv
import unicodecsv as csv
from faker import Factory
from collections import defaultdict

def anonymize_rows(rows):
"""
Rows is an iterable of dictionaries that contain name and
email fields that need to be anonymized.
"""
# Load the faker and its providers
faker  = Factory.create()

# Create mappings of names & emails to faked names & emails.
names  = defaultdict(faker.name)
emails = defaultdict(faker.email)

# Iterate over the rows and yield anonymized rows.
for row in rows:
    # Replace the name and email fields with faked fields.
    row['name']  = names[row['name']]
    row['email'] = emails[row['email']]

    # Yield the row back to the caller
    yield row

#def anonymize('masktest.csv', 'masktest_tgt.csv'):
"""
The source argument is a path to a CSV file containing data to anonymize,
while target is a path to write the anonymized CSV data to.
"""
with open('masktest.csv', 'rU') as f:
with open('masktest_tgt.csv', 'w') as o:
        # Use the DictReader to easily extract fields
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(o, reader.fieldnames)

        # Read and anonymize data, writing to target file.
    for row in anonymize_rows(reader):
        print (row['name'])
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Input: id,name,email,phone
123,dave jackson,dave.jackson@email.com,212-121-3234

masked output: 123,Elizabeth Myers MD,alicia70@hotmail.com,212-121-3234

Comment: Having the same problem...how did you call the function? What command did you have to execute once you had your code in this form?

Comment: Hello Data_Kid, Did you look at the sample I have given. Please check and let me know. I have just used the file name with in def ---> (with open('masktest.csv', 'rU') as f:
with open('masktest_tgt.csv', 'w') as o:)

Comment: It eventually worked . I had to use the csv library and not the unicode. What version of python are you running?

Comment: I'm running on python 2.7.

Comment: I think thats what the issue was . The unicodecsv function will not work with this on python 3.5 and above